# Enhancing RecyclerView Performance in Android for a Facebook-like Social App News Feed with Pagination

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, paging, nestedscrollview, android-paging-library

I am working on a social app where I have the home screen similar to Facebook. I have a list of stories, a list of suggested friends, and wall posts. The wall loads the data in pages. I'm currently using `NestedScrollView` to handle this, but the challenge is that with `NestedScrollView`, `RecyclerView` does not recycle the views, resulting in slow and laggy performance.

I want to use the paging library. I tried implementing a single `RecyclerView` with three different views: one for stories, one for suggested friends, and one for the posts (using pagination). But the posts vertical `RecyclerView` inside my main `RecyclerView` is not recycling the views either (I confirmed it through Layout Inspector), so I'm still facing the same performance issue.

Now my questions are:

1. How can I implement a Facebook-like news feed using pagination and still be able to recycle the views without making the code too complex?
2. How can I handle the situations when the user likes the post? In this case, I have to call the API for the current page again. I use `PagingSource.invalidate()` to do this, but I'm not sure if that's a good way.
3. How can I cache the results so that even when I invalidate the `PagingSource`, the user can still smoothly scroll to the top without waiting for the API calls to get the top data.

Any link open source project will really be appreciated.